# Hash sets or associative arrays in bash

Tags: bash, shell, hashset

In a bash script, how can i achieve the following:

Lets assume we have an associative array as follows:

```
servers = (db-test-1=64, db-test-2=128, db-test-3=32)
```

I want to be able to read the names of the servers, and also the values of the servers representing the size of the server's RAM.

So for example, when i loop through the above so called associated array (i know the syntax above is not correct, but you get the point), i would like to store the server names in a variable called server_name, and the RAM size associated with the server into a variable called mem_size. So the first iteration of the for loop should produce the following when i echo:

```
for i in "${containers[@]}"
    do
        \\some code here to get server names and memory size from the array
        echo "Server Name is" $server_name
        echo "Server Memory size is" $mem_size
done
```

And the Results should be:

```
Server Name is db-test-1
Server Memory Size is 64
```

Comment: You should use `!` before the array name to read its keys: `for i in "${!containers[@]}"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare an associative array with your server name as key and RAM size as value:

```
declare -A servers=([db-test-1]=64 [db-test-2]=128 [db-test-3]=32)
```

Then use it as:

```
for s in "${!servers[@]}"; do
   echo "Server Name: $s => Memory Size: ${servers[$s]}"
done
```

```
Server Name: db-test-1 => Memory Size: 64
Server Name: db-test-2 => Memory Size: 128
Server Name: db-test-3 => Memory Size: 32
```